# How to insert id to database from text input

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I've been searching how to do this for over 2 hours so I'll ask here.

I have an eventlineitems table with product_id. On the create form I want to type the product name and when the form submits the controller sets the product_id for the product with that name.

EventLineItems (hasOne product & belongsTo event)

```
id
event_id
product_id
```

Products

```
id
name
```

EventLineItemsController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate(request(), [

    'event_id' => 'required',
    'product_id' => 'required',
    'quantity' => 'required'

  ]);

  $lineItem = new EventLineItem;

  $lineItem->event_id = $request->input('event_id');
  $lineItem->product_id = $request->input('product_id');
  $lineItem->quantity = $request->input('quantity','1');

  $lineItem->save();

  return back()->with('status','Product Added');

}
```

view.blade

```
<input type="text" name="product_id" id="product_id" class="typeahead form-control" placeholder="Enter a product ID" required>
```

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: i think this is a problem "On the create form I want to type the product name and when the form submits the controller sets the product_id for the product with that name."

Comment: Yes that is my problem, I could send the name in the request but how do i find the id for the associated name and then set my ->save() to save the id of the product. this is a has 1 relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use eloquent to get the product object by name :

```
$product = Product::where('name', '=', request('name'));
```

And then access the product id :

```
$product->id
```

There must be simpler solution and more elegant but it gives you the idea.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah this is what i want, is there a way to have more than one? like if its ID being sent(number) search that or use the name

Comment: Yes from the controller, you could check if `request('name')` is an integer or not and do the needed stuff.

Comment: @devjustin if it solved your question thanks for validate it. ; )

Comment: how would i check? i have ` if (is_integer($request->input('product_id'))){

        $lineItem->product_id = $request->input('product_id');

      }
      else { `

Comment: I got it to work :) used your query and added an ->orWhere('id', '=' , '$request')